# Can't access my www directory apache(did network share the folder)

Tags: server, permissions

I am new to linux and stuff but I had a old pc which no one uses, so installed ubuntu on it to do some web design projects.
Installed apache,php,mysql using synaptic package manager from this guide

http://www.top5hosting.co.uk/blog/uk-hosting/356-how-to-turn-your-old-pc-into-a-linux-ubuntu-server

But when I share my folder /var/www the localhost/www says no directory.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by sharing, but if you are typing `localhost/www` into the web browser you should change it to just `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. The `www` folder is the root of your web server and any path that you enter will be relative to it. For example if a folder is called `/var/www/test` on you machine then the address would be `localhost/test` when viewed from the same computer.

Also note that if you are viewing the web page from another computer, you need to use the real IP address or host name. You can find this by typing `ifconfig` in the terminal. For example, on my computer at home it says, among other things, `inet addr:10.0.0.15`. This means that I need to type `10.0.0.15` in a web browser to access the web server from another computer on the same network.

Comment: I'm accesing from the same computer and the url I'm using is localhost/www and it gives "The requested URL /www/info.php was not found on this server."

Comment: Thanks for help, it was actually I had to change my document root and not the URL or network sharing